# C# XML deserialization XmlAttribute

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-attribute

2Let's say I have this array:

```
<something>
    <items1 note="some text">
        <item1></item1>
        <item1></item1>
        <item1></item1>
    </items1>
    <items2>
        <item2></item2>
        <item2></item2>
        <item2></item2>
    </items2>
</something>
```

And I have a model:

```
public class Something
{
    public string Item1Note { get; set; }
    public List<Item1> Items1 { get; set; }
    public List<Item2> Items2 { get; set; }
}
```

So, Is it possible to deserialize XML into the model so that the attribute note of Items1 node was in property Item1Note. Thx in advance.

**EDIT:** I understand that note is property of Items1, but I don't have such class.

Comment: It is an attribute of `items1` not `something`

Comment: Note is just a child element, with out the `something` root, what is the model that the deserializer can identify.

Comment: Can you show me the code pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class for that xml will be

```
public class Items1
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string note { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public List<item1> item1 { get; set; }
}

public class Item2
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<item2> item2 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRootAttribute("Something", Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public class Something
{
   [XmlElement]
    public Items1 items1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public Item2 item2 { get; set; }
}


Something objSomething = this.Something();

ObjectXMLSerializer<Something>.Save(objSomething, FILE_NAME);

Loading the xml

objSomething = ObjectXMLSerializer<Something>.Load(FILE_NAME);
```

Comment: Main point is I don't want to change model. So it's impossible with current model? Thx.

Comment: if you see i have change the model.. i have mentioned two things one xmlelement and xmlattribute to explain you how note will be coiming you want to generate the xml or read the xml

Comment: and using the objectxml serializer i am loading and saving the object

Comment: Items1 is a wrapper in your example. I just don't want to use wrappers. I hoped for any special XmlAttribute property. :D Something like XmlAttribute("Items1@note") or something... guess no magic here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own parser and then save it as object.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I guess it's a bit too complex for my task. :(